# Configuring two network interfaces in gentoo using dhcpcd

Tags: networking, dhcp, gentoo

There are two network interfaces in my system. net0 and net1. Both are in the default runlevels in gentoo.

The /etc/conf.d/net file contains

Code:

```
config_net0="dhcpcd -b -t 0" and 
config_net1="dhcpcd -b -t  0 -noipv4LL assign_static_ip_address"
```

Now whenever I connect ethernet cable, dhcpcd does it job. net0 takes the ipaddress in 192 range. But if I disconnect the ethernet cable, net0 shows fefo::XXX something. This is due to "net0:waiting for carrier status" and dhcp trying to assign local link address to net1. since I passed -noipv4LL option, the net1 is also not assigned to local link address.

After I surfed in internet, when I passed -K option to net0 . that is
Code:

```
config_net0="dhcpcd -K -b -t 0"
```

the net0 takes local link address.

But the problem is,

I need to reboot the system every time for dhcpcd to assign either IP address when ethernet is connected or assign local link address to net0 interface.
It is not assigned automatically.

How this can be overcome ?

Answer (score 0):

The Gentoo Handbook has a solution in the [Dynamic Networking](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Networking/Dynamic) section. Their suggestion is **ifplugd**. Which would configure much like the standard /etc/conf.d/net but an interface entry would be:

```
ifplugd_net0="dhcpcd -b -t 0" and 
ifplugd_net1="dhcpcd -b -t  0 -noipv4LL assign_static_ip_address"
```